# Question about external USB disk for mac air

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, usb, external-disk, disk-space

So I recently bought just a cheap 32 GB sandisk USB flash drive to add some more space to my macbook air. (I know nothing about this type of stuff so bare with me.) I bought the USB drive so I could download a specific game to my mac. Now, I currently have 80/121 GB available on my flash storage, and the USB drive has 32 GB which I mentioned earlier. To download the game I need like 95 GB (total) of free storage. Basically I just want to know if there is a way to download some of the game to my flash storage and the rest to the USB drive. Or if there is something else I can do just so I can download this game? [image: heres a picture of the storage tab in the about section of my computer]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

With the exception of RAID, which allows you to create one big disk from several smaller ones you can't combine an external USB drive with an internal drive.

So in order to do what you want you would have to have a USB drive with about 100GB of available room on it. Which is eminently practical and do-able. Just more expensive than your 32GB flash drive.

Comment: Might be worth noting that cheap flash drives are not really intended for anything active (like running a game) - they are intended for data storage with infrequent changes. With a 128GB internal drive, I would recommend getting something like a Samsung T5 (or T7) 500GB (or bigger) as additional storage.

Comment: What is with Fusion Drive?

Comment: A Fusion Drive is two **internal** drives, a smaller SSD and a larger HDD, it is a special Apple thing to give you the benefit of a fast SSD with the capacity of a (slower) bigger HDD.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know it is also possible with internal and external together.